# Trying to use **kwargs to define attributes in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

So I have a class that defines characters and its attributes and it goes like this:

```
class character():

    def __init__(self, health, dodge, damage, critAdd):

        self.health=health
        self.dodge=dodge
        self.damage=damage
        self.critAdd=critAdd
```

and when I create an instance as this:

```
knight=character(150, 5, 40, 1.5)
```

it works perfectly. But what I´m trying to create is a way of creating it with key values, like this:

```
knight=character(health=150, dodge=5, damage=40, critAdd=1.5)
```

So i tried to write the `__init__` like this, using *`**kwargs`*:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    self.health=health
    self.dodge=dodge
    self.damage=damage
    self.critAdd=critAdd
```

It says:

```
NameError: name 'health' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? I´m really new to programming so I can´t figure it out.

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to use **kwargs?  Your initial version is _better_, and will still support using keywords / arbitrary order.

Comment: health is not defined. You need to access health in kwargs, which is a dictionary.@wim, at what number of arguments does the original version cease to be better?

Comment: @wim I just thought it would be more organized. I guess I could keep it like that but if I wanted to use **kwargs (so I can understand how it works, kinda confusing for me), could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kwargs` is just a mapping; it doesn't magically create local variables for your function. You need to index the python dictionary with the desired key.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.health = kwargs['health']
    self.dodge = kwargs['dodge']
    self.damage = kwargs['damage']
    self.critAdd = kwargs['critAdd']
```

A [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) simplifies this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Character:
    health: int
    dodge: int
    damage: int
    critAdd: float
```

This generates your original `__init__` automatically.

If you need to do additional work in `__init__` after adding the dataclass decorator you can define `__post_init__` which a dataclass will call after `__init__`.

Comment: If you need to do additional work in the `__init__` after adding the `dataclass` decorator do you continue defining the `__init__` method?

Comment: You can define `__post_init__`, which a dataclass will call after `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to define your method with `**kwargs` to support passing arguments by keyword. Your original version of `__init__` already supports the `character(health=150, dodge=5, damage=40, critAdd=1.5)` syntax you want to use. Your original version is *better* than using `**kwargs`, because it ensures that exactly the right parameters were passed, rejecting things like `helth=150` typos.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `get()`, for example:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

  self.health= kwargs.get('health', 10) # The first argument is the variable you want
                                        # The second is the default in case this kwarg do not exist


a = Example(health=50)
b = Example()

print(a.health)
print(b.health)
```